# Bootstrap 4 mr-auto not working correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="#" alt=" logotype">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-9">
        <div class="head-buttons mr-auto">
          <a href="">Русский</a>
          <div class="auth-buttons">
            <button>Войти</button>
            <button>Регистрация</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

I want col-lg-9 all content in this div align to right. Why `mr-auto` is not working? How I can fix it? I tried and `justify-content-end` on row, not working..

Comment: you should add d-flex justify-content-end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

auto-margins work for flexbox containers, but `col-lg-9` isn't a flexbox container. Use `d-flex` to make it a flexbox container, and then **`ml-auto` to push the content to the right**.

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="#" alt="logotype">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 d-flex">
        <div class="head-buttons ml-auto">
            <a href="">Русский</a>
            <div class="auth-buttons">
                <button>Войти</button>
                <button>Регистрация</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

---

Another option is to use `col-lg-auto` to shrink the width of the right column to its content. Then `ml-auto` on the column will work too.

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="#" alt=" logotype">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-auto ml-auto">
            <div class="head-buttons">
                <a href="">Русский</a>
                <div class="auth-buttons">
                    <button>Войти</button>
                    <button>Регистрация</button>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/4n4R9cNrqE

Answer (score 8):

In bootstrap 5, use `ms-auto` instead of `ml-auto` and `me-auto` instead of `mr-auto`.

```html
<ul className="navbar-nav ms-auto">
<ul className="navbar-nav me-auto">
```

Comment: Damn, the documentation still isn't updated here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#auto-margins

Answer (score 3):

mr-auto is use to set margin-right auto not to use align content to right.

you want to align content to right in col-lg-9 so you need to add class to text-right with col-lg-9.

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you should use class float-right and d-flex instead of mr-auto.

Comment: its work.. but have to add justify-content-end for aligning the text to right

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's just best to use **style** tag to set style="margin-left: auto" then it works perfectly.

Comment: Nice band-aid suggestion!  Helped me in pinch when I was really struggling to get ml-auto to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Nav className="ms-auto"> for float-right
<Nav className="me-auto"> for float-left
```

Comment: It would be great if you add little more explanation when answering

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31407971)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to rename .ml-* and .mr-* to .ms-* and .me-*.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/migration/#utilities-3

Comment: Please elaborate what effect your proposed change will have and why that solves the problem.